# Why should Bottom sheet layout must always be direct child of CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm working with bottom sheets. With other behaviours (like AppBar Scrolling View behaviour), it is possible to mention them in children of different levels, but with bottom sheet behaviour, the ViewGroup has to be direct child of CoordinatorLayout. Why?

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
  <AppbarLayout/>

  <RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout    <!-- not the direct child, still works -->
       ...
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

The below hierarchy does not work.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

  <AppbarLayout/>

  <RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout    <!-- not the direct child, does not work -->
       ...
       app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You can find an alternative solution to this problem, elaborated by Christophe on this [Google+ discussion](http://plus.google.com/106016945094228542183/posts/TqrFtfZ55ZQ)